# Disable Copy and Paste + Right Click on the website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been searching for the solution to fully disable the copy and paste + selection possibility on my website for all devices.
So I have found and implemented this solution on my website:

I've added right below the  tag fallowing JavaScript code:

```js
<script>
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
function mischandler(){
return false;
}
function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
</script>
```

then I have added this CSS to my style.css file:

```
* {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;/*IE,etc*/
  -moz-user-select: none; /*Mozzila Firefox*/
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

First code is blocking right click action on any browser (even for the Enable Copy Chrome extension) and the second one will block a text selection possibility.

All works fine however this solution is not working on mobile, I don't have android phone but I've tested this on iOS device and I can easily select and copy the text from my website.

Is there any other solution I can utilize to disable this on mobile too?

Please don't tell me that I shouldn't do this because the UX or other fancy answers I've already seen. I'm looking for the solution not for the advices...
Thanks so much for your time and I'm sorry if I doubled the thread but I've been told to not ask the question in other posts. So hope this post will be a complete answer to the Copy & Paste subject if solution is found.

Comment: The solution is that there is nothing you can do to stop a determined user from doing ***whatever*** they want with your site.  You are basically trying to stop them from downloading something that they have already downloaded and ***have to*** download in order for your site to function.

Comment: “*Please don't tell me that I shouldn't do this because the UX or other fancy answers I've already seen. I'm looking for the solution not for the advices*” The *fact* that this is extremely poor UX is not a “*fancy answer*”, it’s the truth (inconvenient as it may be). There is no way to prevent this behavior 100%, as users can simply view your page source and copy your content from there with minimal additional effort ***by design***. You *really* should reconsider such a requirement and understand what you’re *truly* trying to prevent, as this method you’re pursuing is not effective at all.

Comment: As above, there are just too many cases that you cannot prevent; wouldn't stop a screen reader/scanner copying text, opening source, saving the html file, you can scrape the site visually if you really wanted. You can put as much of CSS/JS solutions you want but you will not have a working solution meaning is it even worthwhile? (A better solution would be to develop your browser that prevents this).

Comment: By the way, consider that people use selection also for reading aid. I know several people who do this. They select lines or half of the first and half of the second line, and they do this so they can easily follow the text when reading, without skipping lines, just like some people use their finger as reading aid in newspapers and books. You are actively hurting accessibility.

Comment: This is what I love. Do you think I don't know all of this? Of course anyone can open DevTools and copy whatever they want, but I'm doing a website for the client in the Beauty industry where their competitors copying their articles or texts and uses on their FB pages. So, the users we talking about are a beauticians who don't know what are the developers tools or source code or anything you already pointed above?

Comment: Poor UX? How come? What is a deciding factor about poor UX here.  User can view the page, can read the page, page is responsive and well designed, what else the user need? All this conversation is pointless because I will do whatever it takes and I will disable this possibility on the customer website no matter what.

Comment: “*I'm doing a website for the client in the Beauty industry where their competitors copying their articles or texts and uses on their FB pages.*” This is a legal issue, not a technical one.

Comment: EXTENSIONS: Tried few extension's already and copy is not possible. SCREEN READERS? That's ok I'm not trying to limit disabled people so this is actually good that screen reader will read the text. DISCRIMINATING: By what? LEGAL ISSUE: Come on guys! I already tried to minimise all those attacks but you simply need to say something. That's ok

Comment: [First thing I find on Google](https://www.maketecheasier.com/copy-text-from-blocked-website-chrome/) (which for sure will work), [second thing I find on Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-select-and-copy/lamaakaemgdclpnfbofmhpkanfnojjch). In regards to discrimination I was talking about people who have issues reading long lines, as I mentioned above I know several people personally who use selection as reading aid.

Comment: @CherryDT correct! Thank you for your valuable feedback, but like I have already said I'm looking for the solution not for a legal advices. I already knew all this stuff before I came here, thanks for the links yes some extension will still copy and some of them don't and that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WebKit pointer events none. Use the following CSS:

```
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And add the class of `avoid-clicks` to whatever you don't want to have right clicks.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work on iOS

Comment: You could use: touch-action: none; which might work with iOS.

Comment: Ethan, yes, this seams to work on iOS. I had touch action set to pan-y to prevent any horizontal scrolling but this works even better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add these :

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work on iOS